# Bad error message when approving approved edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, edit-rights

Occasionally, on approving a suggested-edit to a post, I receive an error message that indicates that I do not have the privileges to do so:

> An error occurred when trying to approve
>
> You must have edit rights to approve a pending edit

On refreshing the page, I find that the suggested edit no longer shows up on the list. I believe this is a bad error message for "Edit has already been approved / rejected."

[image]

Comment: +1 I've run into the same thing. If a suggested edit gets its quota of votes (which is happening almost instantly right now) voting fails with "You must have edit permissions to approve a suggested edit" which is a misleading message.

Comment: Got it as well. I included a screen.

Comment: +1 I was just about to post the same thing. It looks like a simple bug, but something certainly worth fixing.

Comment: Yep. Suggested edits tend to be processed quickly (perhaps because the marker visibility is high). So this error shows up quite frequently.

Comment: Also, the dots are missing. ;-)

Comment: This is such a noob question, but what is the URL for that page in SO and is there a list of such admin URLs? (I am a 10k user on SO).

Comment: @chibacity: it's last tab on /review

Comment: I just encountered this exact same error message when trying to reject an edit.  Perhaps it is not completely fixed or has been reinstated or something?  I went to the next edit in the list and everything was fine again.  Did the review item somehow disappear during the edit process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I just checked in a comprehensive fix.

We will now silently allow you to reject, rejected edits or approve approved edits.

However, if you try to reject an approved edit we will bring up an error message that asks you to go to the offending post and correct it. (same for approving a rejected edit)

Comment: will be deployed today

Comment: That's not just a fix: nice enhancements!