# Unable to edit my own answer until all other suggested edits are approved/rejected

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

I wanted to edit one of my answers - however, it had a suggested edit by someone else at the time.

Found out I couldn't edit my own answer until the pending edit was either approved or rejected.

I clicked approve - I ended up still waiting for someone else to approve the edit - this goes against point 1 in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits/78331#78331) by Jeff:

> 1. if you own the post you can always one-click reject or accept an edit. So this only applies when you have an "edit collision" on some post that is not yours, but owned by another user.

So, since the answer is owned by me, the suggested edit should have been approved in a one-click by myself. I would call this a bug.

BTW, this is the answer I am talking about:

[are class level public properties thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930848/are-class-level-public-properties-thread-safe/4930869#4930869)

Comment: Peer review history: [1 approval by Oded, followed by 1 reject and 1 approval from others](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/3240). The whole peer reviewing took 27 minutes. Also note that Oded has as much as 80.1k reputation on SO (and that the peer review edit was merely a fix of a typo, and two more words maybe just to circumvent the minimum edit length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK found the bug and fixed it, sorry about it.

Comment: will be deployed later today